# Spectral norm tail bound of a correlated random matrix

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices

I am looking for the tail bound of spectral norm for certain type of random matrix.

Let's say we have a $n\times n$ symmetric random matrix $R$, and for each entry $R_{ij}$, we have that 
$$
E[R_{ij}]=0
$$
$$
Var[R_{ij}]\leq C
$$
$$
|Cov[R_{ij},R_{lm}]|\leq C/n,\quad if\quad (ij\neq lm) \cup (ij\neq ml) 
$$

And I need a tail bound on the spectral norm of $R$.

Our current approach does not utilize the bound on $|Cov[R_{ij},R_{lm}]|$. Our approach is as follows,

---

By Gershgorin circle theorem, we have that 
$$
||R||_2 \leq \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}|
$$

Assume that $Var[R_{ij}]\leq C,\forall i,j$, we also have the following

$$
E[R_{ij}]=0
$$

$$
Var[|R_{ij}|]=E[|R_{ij}|^2]-E^2[|R_{ij}|]=Var[R_{ij}]-E^2[|R_{ij}|] \leq Var[R_{ij}]
$$
and 
$$
C \geq Var[R_{ij}]\geq E^2[|R_{ij}|]
$$

So we have

$$
E[\sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}|] =\sum_{j=1}^n E[ |R_{ij}|] \leq n\sqrt{C}
$$
and 
$$
Var[\sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}|] \leq n^2 Var[R_{ij}] \leq  n^2 C
$$

By Chebyshev's inequality, we have 
$$
{Pr}(\sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}| \geq n\sqrt{C} + k n\sqrt{C} ) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}
$$

And by union bound, we have that
$$
{Pr}(\max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}| \geq n\sqrt{C} + k n\sqrt{C} ) \leq n\frac{1}{k^2}
$$
By setting $k = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\delta }}$, we have that with probability $1-\delta$
$$
||R||_2 \leq \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}| \leq (1+ \sqrt{\frac{n}{\delta }} ) n\sqrt{C}
$$

---

**Our goal is to remove the extra $\sqrt{n}$ in the coefficient**

In our approach, we obtained the tail bound on $\sum_{j=1}^n |R_{ij}|$ by assuming that they are fully correlated (corr=1).

**If we can prove that $|Cov(|R_{ij}|,|R_{ik}|)|\leq \theta C/n$ for some constant $\theta$, we can remove the extra $\sqrt{n}$ directly. But we don't know how to prove it or whether it's true or not.**

Or is there are better way to obtain the tail bound? Is there any result in random matrices literature that can be applied to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now answering my own question. I realize that I can bound the Spectral norm by the Frobenius norm.

The square of Frobenius norm is
$$
||R||_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} R_{ij}^2
$$

So
$$
E[||R||_F^2] = \sum_{i,j} Var[R_{ij}] \leq n^2 C
$$

By Markov inequality, we have

$$
Pr(||R||_F^2 \geq kn^2 C) \leq 1/k
$$

So

$$
Pr(||R||_F \geq n \sqrt{kC}) \leq 1/k
$$

By setting $k=1/\delta$, we have

$$
Pr(||R||_2 \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\delta}} \sqrt{C}) \leq Pr(||R||_F \geq \frac{n}{\sqrt{\delta}} \sqrt{C}) \leq \delta
$$